# Mysql trigger add number to new value on duplicate key

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to import data to a new table, but turns out some values from two different columns are duplicate, but it seems to not be working. This is what my trigger looks like:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER insert_specificationattributeoption_child AFTER INSERT ON import_specificationattributeoption FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO t_virtuemart_customs (virtuemart_custom_id, custom_parent_id, custom_title, show_title, field_type, custom_params, created_on, created_by, ordering, modified_on, modified_by)
    VALUES (NEW.option_id, NEW.specification_attribute_id, NEW.option_name, lower(NEW.option_name), 'S', 0, current_time(), 633, NEW.display_order, current_time(), 633)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE NEW.option_id = NEW.option_id + 5000;
END //
```

With the trigger I don't get the duplicate key error, but I don't see any key being over 5000. What am I doing wrong there? Would it be better to "find" the highest id and adding the new id to it instead?

**Edit:** Basically what I want to do is, if I'm inserting a primary key that already exists, change the value I want to insert.

Comment: Is virtuemart_custom_id an auto_increment primary key?

Comment: Does any of these "virtuemart_custom_id, custom_parent_id, custom_title, show_title, field_type, custom_params, created_on, created_by, ordering, modified_on, modified_by" have Unique Key set in the table?

Comment: @P.Salmon yes, it is.

Comment: @wast The only Unique one is `virtuemart_custom_id`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not clear what you are trying to do. The trigger must be detecting the duplicate key because no duplicate error is being shown but UPDATE NEW.option_id = NEW.option_id + 5000 has no effect on the table. If you want to amend the table then the syntax would be UPDATE option_id = NEW.option_id + 5000 -note this also amends the next auto_increment value to NEW.option_id + 5000 + 1.

Comment: While this works, it is updating the existing information, and I want to update the one you're inserting. If I have an existing value of `1`, and insert another `1`, it will change the previous one to `5001`, and not insert the new one. What I want is to keep the old item with id of `1`, and change the new one to `5001`.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to accept the duplicate with a new id but maintain the the relationship to the original via custom_parent_id?

Comment: Exactly! Sorry for being so bad at explaining it.